# memory leaked with pthread_cancel() itself

Tags: c, pthreads

I created a JOINABLE thread and later canceled it near the end of the program, e.g.

```
rc2 = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
rc2 = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
rc2 = pthread_create(&destroy_thread, &attr, destroy_expired_sessions, NULL);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
...
rc2 = pthread_cancel(destroy_thread);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
rc2 = pthread_join(destroy_thread, &status);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 || (int *)status != PTHREAD_CANCELED);
```

Yet, there is memory leak with pthread_cancel(), analyzed by valgrind:

```
==17583== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==17583==    at 0x4006878: malloc (in /m/mls/pkg/trees/2008Q3/ix86-Linux-RHEL5/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==17583==    by 0x79FAC1: _dl_map_object_deps (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x7A4A67: dl_open_worker (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x7A0DA5: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x7A43F1: _dl_open (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x8BF2E1: do_dlopen (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x7A0DA5: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x8BF494: __libc_dlopen_mode (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x9527D6: pthread_cancel_init (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x94EC1B: pthread_cancel (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==17583==    by 0x80860CF: authDeinit (authAPI.c:1545)
==17583==    by 0x807F280: main (test_sessionList.c:124)
==17583== 
==17583== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17583==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==17583==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==17583==    still reachable: 28 bytes in 1 blocks.
==17583==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

It seems a defect of the function pthread_cancel() itself. Looks like it malloc()'ed some memory but didn't free() it later. Is there any way to avoid the memory leak here?

Comment: Seems possibly related to dynamic loading, does it leak more than once in that function?

Comment: @Joachim: So far, it seems only to leak once. But, it is still a thorn. :(

Comment: Are you initializing any variables in the thread?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: Yeah, some variables are intialized in the thread, but all in the stack, nothing in the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `pthread_cancel()` is designed to work. When called, it'll call `pthread_cancel_init()` to ensure that several items are dynamically linked (using equivalents to `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`). Those dynamically linked functions/symbols are intended to be available for the remainder of the process' lifetime.

So this isn't a leak in the sense that something has been lost track of - rather it's something loaded and intended to remain alive.

I'd suggest that valgrind be configured to ignore this allocation if possible.

Comment: Hmmm, so you mean it is a false alarm? But where does the malloc() on the top come from? It looks suspicious.

Comment: Just did some research in the web. It seems someone else agree with you, Michael. Look at here: [Valgrind suppression fail is outdated](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588997). It seems a bug of Valgrind, doesn't it?

Comment: Here's the relevant code from glibc source: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/sysdeps/pthread/unwind-forcedunwind.c  Presumably, `__libc_dlopen()` allocates a block of memory which is never freed because the `dlopen` handle is never freed (by design).  I think valgrind should be configured to ignore this, but I'm not familiar enough with the tool to be able to explain how that should be done best.

Comment: @QiangXu: the bug report you pointed to indicates this should have been fixed by Valgrind a while back - I wonder if there's been a change in glibc since then that avoids the valgrind fix? The call stack in your dump looks slightly different than those in the valgrind bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your memory leak is designated as "reachable" means that you simply didn't call `free` on the pointer ... in other words the pointer is still an accessible pointer, and it's still pointing to the allocated memory when the process completes. The pointer did not go out-of-scope, which would make a situation where you've completely "lost" the memory reference and cannot call `free` on it.

Sometimes holding dynamic memory allocations for the entirety of the process can be a desirable trait, such as using dynamic memory to avoid static initialization issues as [described here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15). You haven't posted enough code to actually diagnose what the exact issue is, but I highly doubt the issue is with `pthread_cancel` itself, but rather has to-do with how you're moving memory around via pointers in your code, where it seems some of those pointers aren't exactly leaking memory, but rather are just still holding onto the memory they point to when the process completes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jason. But the problem here looks not related to my code. Rather, it is either a problem of pthread_cancel() itself, or a problem of Valgrind.

Comment: BTW, I hope you aren't feeling like I'm "blaming" your code ... I'm actually trying to point out that sometimes holding onto dynamic memory for the entirety of a process is actually something *desirable* rather than something to be avoided.

Comment: Nah, I am not feeling you are blaming my code at all. Rather, you are suggesting some good coding practice. I rather appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to forcibly terminate a thread.  It's better to come up with a clean way to signal the thread to exit on it's own (and do it's own resource cleanup).  Then call just pthread_join to finish the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding, Selbie. But the thread here is always running, not intended to end, except at the end of the whole process. So, we've got to finish it from outside. And yes, we do have some cleanup handler. :)

Comment: Why make it joinable then?  Why not just call `pthread_detach`, or set the attributes to detachable?

Comment: @Jason: Because I want to use pthread_join() after pthread_cancel() to make sure the thread does get canceled. So I created the thread as joinable. Is there any potential side effect on this?

Comment: @QiangXu : If you want the thread to run the entirety of the process, then there is no need to make a thread joinable.  Ending the process by either calling `exit()` or returning from `main` will simply kill all the detached threads that have been spawned by the process ... in other words the OS will reclaim all the resources used by the process.

Comment: @Jason: Yup, you are right. The kernel can help me handle the reclaiming actually. I just want to relieve the kernel of this burden, and do the necessary cleaning-up by myself before the program ends. Isn't it a good practice? By the way, I am still a bit hazy about the downside of a joinable thread (vs a detached one). Could you elaborate more on this point? Thanks!

Comment: @QiangXu : You generally want to make a thread joinable when you need to manage it's lifetime.  A typical example may be something like an asynchronous worker thread or thread pool.  In other words, you only want the results when the thread has completed.  If an error has occurred, you would want to know that too.  Threads where you don't need to manage the lifetime can be detachable.  If a thread is launched to run for the entirety of the process, then it's lifetime isn't really being managed.  The fact that you're forcing the thread to quit sort of indicates this lack of lifetime management.

Comment: @QiangXu - unnecessary explicit thread termination is very common.  Some developer, somewhere, once said that all threads, always, have to be joined with and terminated before the 'main thread' exits, no matter whether the thread is meant to run forever or not. Sadly, other developers believed this and tried to terminate threads that were internally blocked.  They then posted to StackOverflow saying 'How do I kill my threads because my app will not shut down', and were advised not to make long-term blocking calls.  This makes developers like me bang my head repeatedly on the keyboard.

Comment: +1 for Jason for not bothering about spurious output from Valgrind and for explaining the futility/madness of joing every thread no matter what.  TBH, I should make it +10.